# jQuery datatable checkall

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

HTML

```
<div class="box">
<table id="Datatable">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th><input name="checkall" type="checkbox" class="checkall" value="ON" /></th>
         <th>field</th>
         <th>field</th>
         <th>field</th>
         <th>field</th>
         <th>field</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="checkers"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]"/></th>
        <td>value</td>                                          
        <td>value</td>  
        <td>value</td>  
        <td>value</td>  
        <td>value</td>  
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make the checkall checkbox selects all the checkboxes using this code:

```
$('.checkall').click(function () {
        var checkall =$(this).parents('.box:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        $.uniform.update(checkall);
    });
```

As datatable shows the first 10,20,30 ... etc rows and removes the others from the DOM to do the pagination, this jQuery code only selects the rows in the current page. So is there anyway that I can select all checkboxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found the solution

```
$('.checkall', oTable.fnGetNodes()).click(function () {
```

Answer (score 7):

My solution works too:

```
$('.checkall').click(function(e) {

          var chk = $(this).prop('checked');

          $('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).prop('checked',chk);
        });
```

And if you want check only filtered (if you use dom for filtering in datatables), then you can use this, to check only filtered

```
$('.checkall').click(function(e) {

          var chk = $(this).prop('checked');

          $('input', oTable.$('tr', {"filter": "applied"} )).prop('checked',chk);
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Old thread but I have a few contributions.

To auto-generate a checkbox column rather than doing this inline, add this to your column definition:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ { "mRender": function (data, type, full) { 
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="id" class="class" value="' + data + '">'; },  "aTargets": [0] } ]

// Note: aTargets is the zero-indexed array determining placement of the checkbox column
// "aTargets": [0] gives you the first column (first from left)
```

As RUN-CMD suggested you can use TableTools to handle row-selection, but this didn't help op because selecting / highlighting all rows is separate from checking the row's input. However, it is a nice visual enhancer.

We can programmatically check the row's checkbox by adding this code to the _fnRowSelect() function in TableTools.js (function is lines 1079 - 1119 in my file) :

```
// This marks them as selected
    for ( i=0, len=data.length ; i<len ; i++ )
    {
        data[i]._DTTT_selected = true;

        if ( data[i].nTr )
        {
            $(data[i].nTr).addClass( that.classes.select.row );
            // Now if there's a checkbox somewhere in the row - we check it
            $(data[i].nTr).closest("tr").find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
        }
    }
```

And while we're editing this file, let's make a new TableTools button that toggles select all / select none. Now we won't have to bind both functions onto one button.

We'll create this button right after select all and select none buttons in TableTools.js (beginning at line 2393 in my file):

```
/* Combines select_all and select_none buttons
 * Default button text is a checkbox
 * to strip button style and use a checkbox alone put this on native page: 
 * $(".select-all-master").removeClass("btn");
 */
"select_master": $.extend( {}, TableTools.buttonBase, {
    "sButtonText": '<input type="checkbox" id="master_check" class="row_checks master_check" value="">',
    "sButtonClass": "select-all-master",
    "sAction": "div",
    "sTag": "div",
    "fnClick": function( nButton, oConfig ) {
        var that = this;
        var selected = false;
        $("table tr").each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                selected = true;
            }
        });
        if (selected==false) {
            that.fnSelectAll();
            $("#master_check").prop('checked', 'checked');
        }
        if (selected==true) {
            that.fnSelectNone();
            $("#master_check").prop('checked', '');
            selected = false;
        }
    }
} ),
```

Now we can apply our select all / none toggle by calling it as we would any TableTools button. In our table tools init:

```
"aButtons": [ { "sExtends": "select_master","sToolTip": "Tool tip to display on checkbox hover" } ]
```

Also in your native datatables init you can use:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select-all-master").appendTo("thead#selectallbtn");
    $(".select-all-master").removeClass("btn");
});
```

html:

```
<thead class="selectallbtn"></thead>
```

If you want to remove the button style and put it into your table header as a normal checkbox all / none controller.
If you're not using bootstrap, consider doing something like this ([link](http://bit.ly/10tLQIY)) in your CSS and code should work fine.

Provided everything went smoothly for you, the result should be something this: http://screencast.com/t/c3ZDi0mmiGj

Biggest convenience is targeting the checkbox :checked property from anywhere inside the row, not just on clicking checkbox. Helpful for high res users or mobile touchpunch / touchstart.

Answer (score 0):

datatables provides a plugin "TableTools" which includes this functionality.

http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

here are examples of row selection, both for single-select and mulit-select:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/select_single.html

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/select_multi.html

additionally, when you initialize your datatable with the TableTools plugin activated, you get access to the following API methods:

- fnIsSelected
- fnSelect
- fnSelectAll
- fnSelectNone

the API methods are documented here:
http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/api

Answer (score -2):

I think that it is not possible, I 'd use another parameter to notify the server that all the records were checked. In that way you could implement you logic for check all on server side.

Comment: Of course this is possible, and there are several methods for achieving it. See examplee here: http://screencast.com/t/c3ZDi0mmiGj  
Furthermore, you don't have to update anything on the server until you are assigning an action to the checked boxes (i.e. delete rows, change row value etc.) of course some actions client side actions like printing will be available without performing any server requests.